# Getting the LatLng from placed marker for browser fields

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Tried the following scripts but the last section is not working. Help please.

// script type="text/javascript"

```
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-36.624345125527526,144.96459973437504),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    streetViewControl: false,
    draggableCursor: 'crosshair',
    draggingCursor: 'pointer'
    };
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
    });

map.panTo(position);
```

// not working

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    var point = marker.getPosition();
    document.getElementById("latitude").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = point.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = point.lng();
    });
```

// end of script

---

Tried using the following but nothing happen after the marker is drag. Seems like the listener is not listening to the 'dragend' event of the marker. Any clue? Other option to get the latLng after dragging marker on map?

// JS code

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    var point = e.latLng;
    alert(marker.e.latLng);
})
```

// end code

The input elements part is not a choice as the scripts sit in an embedded placeholder of a web based application. So can't change that part.

Comment: I have only used google maps api a little, but your `map.panTo(position)` looks oddly placed to me.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `MouseEvent` object passed by the dragend event for the marker.  Like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {
    var point = e.latLng;
    document.getElementById("latitude").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = point.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = point.lng();
    });
```

I also am not sure why you're not just naming your input elements and accessing them directly...something like this:

```
document.getElementById("latitude_input").value = point.lat();
document.getElementById("longitude_input").value = point.lng();
```

Comment: Tried using the following but still not working. Any clue? The inpu elements part is not a choice as the scripts sit in an embedded placeholder of a web based application. So can't change that part.    
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(e) {    
   var point = e.latLng;    
   alert(marker.e.latLng);    
});

Comment: Post your live code somewhere (JS Fiddle would work) and that way evertone can take a look and see where the error may be.